# camunda spring boot external tasks do not run in parallel

Tags: spring-boot, task, external, camunda

I created a small camunda application with spring boot. all tasks are external.The probliem,Is I the taks do not run n parallel . just one task at a time .
And one of the tasks doenot complete until ,I close the spring boot application.
Please help
Adding the following to application.yml did not solve the problem
spring.task.execution.pool:
core-size: 10
max-size: 20
spring.task.scheduling:
pool.size: 20

@Component
@ExternalTaskSubscription("getCustomers") // create a subscription for this topic name
public class GetCustomers implements ExternalTaskHandler {

```
@Resource(name = "amlDataSourceJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
```

public void execute(ExternalTask externalTask, ExternalTaskService externalTaskService) {
Logger.getLogger("GetCustomers").log(Level.INFO, "worker: GetCustomers started" );

```
String sql = "SELECT cust_i_id FROM CUSTOMERS";

List<String> customersList =  jdbc.query(
        sql,
        (rs, rowNum) ->
                new String(
                        rs.getString("cust_i_id")
                )
);



// we could call an external service to create the loan documents here

// complete the external task
VariableMap variables = Variables.createVariables();
variables.put(Common.VAR_NAME_CUSTOMERS_LIST, customersList);
 

Logger.getLogger("GetCustomers").log(Level.INFO, "worker: GetCustomers finished" );
// complete the external task
externalTaskService.complete(externalTask, variables);
```

// externalTaskService.complete(externalTask);
Logger.getLogger("GetCustomers").log(Level.INFO, "worker: GetCustomers Task completed" );

}

}

Comment: Can you please share some of the code you used for the external task worker?

Comment: I modified the post with code of one worker

Comment: How have you modeled this? What makes you expect that tasks should exist / run in parallel? Is it because you start multiple process instances? How many task is the worker fetching at a time (camunda:  bpm:    client:    max-tasks:) ?

Comment: i started two instances of two diferent process definitions.the two external workers exist in the same spring boot project. lookin at the console log , itis obvious they not run in parallel